# Glassfish embedded with JUnit for EJB testing

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, junit4, ejb-3.1, glassfish-embedded

I ran into a big issue, what I cannot solve.

I trying write a small application with JavaEE6 and EJB. I would like set up testing environment with EJBContainer and Glassfish Embedded.

This project is created via Maven but the EJBContainer is booted up by the test class itself because as I see it is easier and more common than booting up from maven.

I created a GlassFish domain based on some articles in my src/test/glassfish-domain folder (in the right structure, see below).

If my domains.xml does not contains my JDBC resource what I define to test my application, GF embedded boots up correctly. But when I define the required JDBC resource, I got a NullPointerException without explanation.

Can anyone point me, what I do wrong?

Domain Config snippet:

```
 <resources>
    <!-- [...] -->
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="bookshelf" jdni-name="jdbc/bookshelf" />
    <jdbc-connection-pool driver-classname="" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" description="" name="bookshelf">
      <property name="User" value="APP"></property>
      <property name="DatabaseName" value="bookshelf-db"></property>
      <property name="RetrieveMessageText" value="true"></property>
      <property name="Password" value="APP"></property>
      <property name="ServerName" value="localhost"></property>
      <property name="Ssl" value="off"></property>
      <property name="SecurityMechanism" value="4"></property>
      <property name="ConnectionAttributes" value=";create=true"></property>
      <property name="TraceFileAppend" value="false"></property>
      <property name="TraceLevel" value="-1"></property>
      <property name="PortNumber" value="1527"></property>
      <property name="LoginTimeout" value="0"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
  </resources>
  <servers>
    <server name="server" config-ref="server-config">
      <!-- [...] -->
      <resource-ref ref="jdbc/bookshelf" />
    </server>
```

The log:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:233)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:129)
    at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
    at me.hron.bookshelf.test.ejb.CategoryFacadeTest.setupContainer(CategoryFacadeTest.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.Resources$Duck.getResourceByName(Resources.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Dom.invokeDuckMethod(Dom.java:946)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Dom.invoke(Dom.java:899)
    at org.glassfish.config.support.TranslatedConfigView.invoke(TranslatedConfigView.java:119)
    at $Proxy58.getResourceByName(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceManager.isBindableResourceEnabled(ResourceManager.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceManager.deployResources(ResourceManager.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.services.ResourceManager.postConstruct(ResourceManager.java:116)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
    at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:203)
... 25 more
```

Comment: Update: I found a first mistake, a typo in the config (jdni vs jndi), but there is an another problem:

    WARNING: RAR8035: Exception while creating jdbc connection pool [ bookshelf ] : , com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Unable to find location for module : __ds_jdbc_ra

Comment: Hey, i was struggling with that error too, not being able to find location for module ...
The thing was a wrong folder structure in the glassfish placed in the test folder. 
I had _src/test/glassfish/lib/applications/__ds_jdbc_ra_. I was missing the _install_ folder under _lib_, so the right structure is _src/test/glassfish/lib/install/applications/__ds_jdbc_ra_ That solved the issue for me.

Comment: I will give a try for that when  i have a time. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

glassfish folder has to have a lib

structure is like this

```
lib
+install
++aplications
```

which has

```
jaxr-ra
jmsra
__cp_jdbc_ra
__dm_jdbc_ra
__ds_jdbc_ra
__xa_jdbc_ra
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a 2 years old thread and I do not have the source of the application anymore. It was a playground project and I deleted it few months ago when I migrated to my new laptop. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I had the same problem and the proposed solution worked for me. Thank you!